# How to update MySql Database from DataGrid on C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to update MySQL DB from DataGrid, but it isn't working. The added data is not in the database, and there are no errors, why this happens. I have been trying to solve this problem for several days now.

```
private void dtGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {    
        MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
        string table = "brands";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM "+table;
        MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
        myDataAdapter.InsertCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
        myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        myDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, table);
        myDataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet, table);
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: did you delete the lines where you add the content? Or did you miss it? All what I see is that you update with the unchanged DataSet.

Comment: @DanielW. How to update it? I'm trying Insert values in DB from DataGrid

Comment: Yiou need to add the data to the myDataSet  before you call myDataAdapter.Update

Comment: @DanielW. How did it?

Comment: @DanielW. I did it, but it's insert all the data and I only need new

Comment: I'm not sure, but  myDataAdapter.Fill seams to be not necessary and cousing that all data are added and not only new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Eugene

so here:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dt = ((DataView)dtGrid.ItemsSource).ToTable() as DataTable;
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

then populating it again with

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(ds, table);
```

You are creating a new datatable, then adding an existing data table to it. That is why all rows are getting added again.

Try changing your code to. XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="310" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-1,-1,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="763">
        <TabItem Header="Brands" Name="tabBrands">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dtGrid" Height="280" Width="750" BeginningEdit="dtGrid_BeginningEdit" RowEditEnding="dtGrid_RowEditEnding" AutoGenerateColumns="True" AutoGeneratingColumn="dtGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />               
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Later" Name="tabItem2">

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter;        
    private DataSet myDataSet;
    private MySqlCommandBuilder myBuilder;
    private MySqlConnection myConn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myConn.Open();
        myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter {SelectCommand=new MySqlCommand() {Connection=myConn, CommandText= "SELECT * FROM brands" } };
        myDataSet = new DataSet();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "brands");           
        dtGrid.DataContext = myDataSet.Tables["brands"].DefaultView;
    }

    private void dtGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        myBuilder  = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
        DataRowView myDRV = (DataRowView)dtGrid.SelectedItem;
        myDRV.BeginEdit();
    }

    private void dtGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView myDRV = (DataRowView)dtGrid.SelectedItem;
        myDRV.EndEdit();
        myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet, "brands");
    }

    private void dtGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var tc = e.Column as System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn;
        var b = tc.Binding as System.Windows.Data.Binding;

        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        b.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        b.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
    }

}
```

this loses the buttons, but you can both edit and add rows now without the need for buttons. To add a row go to the blank row at the bottom of the DataGrid.

Comment: Thank you so much, the only problem in your code is { QuotePrefix = "[", QuoteSuffix = "]" }, I corrected it and everything works, thank you again

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. Sorry about the error, the "[  ]" is SQL syntax, I expect it's different for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running this code once the edit has already been made by the user, going by the name "`RowEditEnding`".

So I think the problem is that you are only creating the `MySqlCommandBuilder` after the edit has been made.

You need to create the `MySqlCommandBuilder` first, then make your edits, then get your update/insert/delete command.

e.g. something like the following (sorry in VB, but you get the gist):

```
Using NotesDS As New DataSet
        Using NotesDA As New SqlDataAdapter With {.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand With {.Connection = SQLDBConnection, .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE ID = " & ID}}
            NotesDA.Fill(NotesDS, "Notes")
            Using NotesDV As New DataView(NotesDS.Tables("Notes"))
                Using NoteBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(NotesDA) With {.QuotePrefix = "[", .QuoteSuffix = "]"}                        
                    If NotesDV.Count = 1 Then                             
                        Dim NoteDRV As DataRowView = NotesDV(0)
                        NoteDRV.BeginEdit()
                        NoteDRV.Item("UserName") = UserName
                        NoteDRV.Item("Note") = Note
                        NoteDRV.Item("NoteDate") = NoteDate
                        NoteDRV.Item("CompanyCode") = CompanyCode
                        NoteDRV.EndEdit()
                        NotesDA.UpdateCommand = NoteBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
                        NotesDA.Update(NotesDS, "Notes")
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

**Edit**

@Eugene, what is your `DataGrid` bound to? Presumably you are setting a `DataView` as the `DataContext`?

If that is the case then you will have used a `DataAdapter` to populate the `DataView` on, maybe, page load? This is the `DataAdapter` you need to initialise your `MySqlCommandBuilder` with.

Try the following:

- declare you `DataAdapter`, `DataSet` and `DataView` at the top of your page.
- Use the `BeginningEdit` handler of your dtGrid to initialise your `MySqlCommandBuilder`on your declared `DataAdapter`
- Use the `RowEditEnding` to run the `DataAdapter.Update` command

e.g. (I am using SQL, but MySQL works the same, to my knowledge)

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;    
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace testApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter;
        private DataView myDataView;
        private DataSet myDataSet;
        private SqlCommandBuilder myBuilder;
        private SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("CONNECTIONSTRING");
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter {SelectCommand=new SqlCommand() {Connection=myConn, CommandText="SELECT MINumber, CompanyName FROM EIncCompanies WHERE CompanyName LIKE 'Test%'" } };
            myDataSet = new DataSet();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "EIncCompanies");
            myDataView = new DataView(myDataSet.Tables["EIncCompanies"]);
            dtGrid.DataContext = myDataView;
        }

        private void dtGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
        {
            myBuilder  = new SqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter) { QuotePrefix="[", QuoteSuffix="]"};
            DataRowView myDRV = (DataRowView)dtGrid.SelectedItem;
            myDRV.BeginEdit();
        }

        private void dtGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView myDRV = (DataRowView)dtGrid.SelectedItem;
            myDRV.EndEdit();
            myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = myBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet, "EIncCompanies");
        }

    }
}
```

I also set `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the binding in the `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon, I did differently, at the moment it inserts all the values from the dtGrid, and not just the new ones, maybe I do not share it correctly.
For for filling dbGrid:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        /*string sql = "SELECT * FROM brands";*/
        MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from brands", conn);
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        conn.Close();
        dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

For Insert new items

```
        private void Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
        string table = "brands";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
        MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dt = ((DataView)dtGrid.ItemsSource).ToTable() as DataTable;
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        myDataAdapter.InsertCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
        myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
        myDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = myCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(ds, table);
        myDataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        myDataAdapter.Update(ds, table);
    }
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TechD.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="TechDep" Height="390" Width="902">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="310" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-1,-1,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="763">
        <TabItem Header="Brands" Name="tabBrands">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="280" Name="dtGrid" Width="750" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowEditEnding="dtGrid_RowEditEnding" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Later" Name="tabItem2">

        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <Button Content="Insert" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="774,21,0,0" Name="Insert" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Click="Insert_Click" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="774,50,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="774,79,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="774,108,0,0" Name="button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" />
</Grid>
```